# read from a formatted test file using fscanf() in c

Tags: c, file-io

Here is the text file

```
Username:user1  Password:pass1
Username:user2  Password:pass2
```

I want to read the username and password from the text. the problem is there is not way to change the format of the text. i tried to read but as there is not space between colon(:), it gives whole `username:user1` as string but i want only user1. i referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528212/using-fscanf-to-skip-a-string) question but it did not help as there is no space between colon.

I tried :

```
 while ((fscanf(fp,"Username:%s Password:%s",username,password))!=EOF)
```

but it gives many undefined characters after user1 and loop never ends.

Comment: You should consult the relevant documentation about the meaning of `fscanf()`s return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char username[128];
    char password[128];
    FILE *fp;
    int ret;

    fp = fopen("read.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Failed to open a file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        ret = fscanf(fp, "Username:%s Password:%s\n",username,password);
        if (ret == EOF)
            break;
        if (ret == 2)
            printf("%s %s\n", username, password);
        else {
            printf("%d\n", ret);
            perror("fscanf:");
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "Username:%s Password:%s\n",username,password)` -- note that it is bad practice to use trailing whitespace characters in `scanf()` format strings. Since the input is from a file, this will work as expected, but this is a common error when using `scanf()` for interactive input where it causes problems. Better to place a space at the beginning of the format string to consume previous newline characters: `fscanf(fp, " Username:%s Password:%s",username,password)`.

Comment: Also, maximum widths should be specified when reading strings using `%s` or `%[]` to avoid buffer overflow: `fscanf(fp, " Username:%127s Password:%127s",username,password)`.

Comment: why you checked ret value to be 2 ? in if(ret == 2) ?

Comment: @JayJoshi  you need to look at fscanf function return value:
 On  success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided
       for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

       The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion  or  a  matching  failure
       occurs.   EOF  is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set,
       and errno is set to indicate the error.

Comment: @PrabhakarLad -- "EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set to indicate the error. " Note that this is not in the Standard, but is a POSIX extension.

Comment: @DavidBowling thank you that was more clearer explanation.

Comment: the call to `printf()` modifies the value of `errno`.  so the first couple of lines of the read loop should be: `while (1) { if( 2 != fscanf(fp, " Username:%127s Password:%127s", username, password ) )  { perror( "fscanf failed" ); fclose(fp); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }   // implied else, fread successful  printf("%s %s\n", username, password); }`

Answer (score 0):

I would use this algorithm:

1. Read while char read isn't ':'
2. Start storing all next chars on username var while the char read is !=' '
3. Remove the last space on the username string
4. Repeat step 1.
5. Same as step 2 but now we store the read data on password value while the read char is != ''\n'
6. Repeat while ! end of file